# showing Y axis in a chart using CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, canvasjs

I made a chart that shows machines and the times that was taken for them to be fixed (machines X, time Y)
the data is loaded dynamically via mysql like the following

```
<?php
include_once(“connexion.php”);
ini_set(‘max_execution_time’,300);
//ini_set(‘error_reporting’, E_ALL);

$sq = “select machine,date_tech,time(time_fin – time_deb) as diff from action_archiv_tech WHERE (date_tech BETWEEN ‘2018-09-10’ AND ‘2018-10-06’)”;
$r = mysql_query($sq) or (die(mysql_error()));
while($tab = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
$machine = $tab[‘machine’];
$diff = $tab[‘diff’];
// $data[] = [“label”=>$machine, “y”=>$diff];
$data[] = array(
‘label’ => $tab[‘machine’],
‘y’ => $tab[‘diff’]
);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=”UTF-8”>
<script>

window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(“chartContainer”, {
theme:”light2″,
animationEnabled: true,
title:{
text: “PM”
},
axisY :{
includeZero: false,
title: “Heures”,
suffix: “H”
},
toolTip: {
shared: “true”
},
legend:{
cursor:”pointer”,
itemclick : toggleDataSeries
},
data: [
{
type: “spline”,
showInLegend: true,
yValueFormatString: “##.00H”,
name: “Curative”,
dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
}

]
});
chart.render();

function toggleDataSeries(e) {
if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === “undefined” || e.dataSeries.visible ){
e.dataSeries.visible = false;
} else {
e.dataSeries.visible = true;
}
chart.render();
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id=”chartContainer” style=”height: 370px; max-width: 1920px; margin: 0px auto;”></div>
<script src=”../../canvasjs.min.js”></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However the results are not like the expected

results : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyIZM.png

Could you please help me figure out how to solve this problem :)

Comment: You know the `php`will execute and end before any `javascript`... If you can give an example of the `php` output then maybe some further assistance could be given. Also, since the chart data is dynamic would it not be easier to use `ajax` to get the data from a server-side page/script-`php` once the page has loaded? That way you can call or execute `new CanvasJS.Chart` with the `php` response...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are passing date-time in y-values, whereas CanvasJS supports only numeric in axisY. Please refer [documentation](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/y/) for more info. However you can workaround this by passing -values as timestamp and format the value in axis-labels and toolTip as shown in below example, here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/b6c34mmv/) for the same.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Machine Operating Time"
  },
  axisY: {
    minimum: (new Date(2016, 0, 25, 17, 30)).getTime(),            
    interval: (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    labelFormatter: function(e){
      return CanvasJS.formatDate(e.value, "DD-MMM h:mm TT");
    }
  },
  toolTip:{
    contentFormatter: function ( e ) {
      return "<strong>Machine " + e.entries[0].dataPoint.label + "</strong></br> Start Time: " +  CanvasJS.formatDate(e.entries[0].dataPoint.y[0], "DD-MMM h:mm TT") + "</br> Stop Time: " +  CanvasJS.formatDate(e.entries[0].dataPoint.y[1], "DD-MMM h:mm TT");  
    }},
  data: [{
      type: "rangeColumn",
      dataPoints: [
        { label: "A", y: [(new Date(2016, 0, 25, 18, 30)).getTime(), (new Date(2016, 0, 26, 11, 00)).getTime()] }, //.getTime() returns timestamp => y-value is numeric
        { label: "B", y: [(new Date(2016, 0, 26, 12, 00)).getTime(), (new Date(2016, 0, 27, 14, 00)).getTime()] },
        { label: "C", y: [(new Date(2016, 0, 27, 3, 30)).getTime(), (new Date(2016, 0, 27, 14, 00)).getTime()] },
        { label: "D", y: [(new Date(2016, 0, 27, 12, 00)).getTime(), (new Date(2016, 0, 28, 14, 00)).getTime()] }  
      ]
  }]                      
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
```